# line.find won't compile, line is not declared

Tags: c++, c-strings

I am a very novice programmer, and I am trying to understand the find functions for strings. At uni we are told to use c-strings, which is why I think that it isn't working. The problem comes when I compile, there is a compile error that `line` was not declared. This is my code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char test[256];
    char ID[256];


    cout << "\nenter ID: ";

    cin.getline(ID, 256);

    int index = line.find(ID);

    cout << index << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Please help, it has become really frustrating as I need to understand this function to complete my assignment :/

Comment: Where exactly to you think `line` is declared *in your code* ?

Comment: see, I thought that it would be test, but when I substituted it for test.find(ID), there was another compile error, so iassumed that that wasn't the problem

Comment: `test` is just an array.  Perhaps you meant to make it a `std::string` so you could use those member functions?

Comment: Are you trying to use C-strings or C++ strings? If the former, why would you use `find`, which doesn't work on C-strings. If the latter, why aren't you actually using them?!

Comment: I wanted to use character arrays, becasue thats what I have been using for the rest of my assignment as opposed to strings, but I tried changing them to 'std::string' but it still wouldnt compile

Comment: It would if it did something like [this instead](http://ideone.com/c4dwqq).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I assume I am using c-strings, but I just assumed the string function would work, I don't know very much I have only been studying this subject for a couple of weeks now

Comment: Places that teach this crap shouldn't be allowed to call themselves "universities"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use C-style strings. But `find` is a member of the C++ `string` class. If you want to use C-style strings, use functions that operate on C style strings like `strcmp`, `strchr`, `strstr`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you actually input some data into `test` also, then one way to do it would be:

```
char *found = strstr(test, ID);

if ( !found )
    cout << "The ID was not found.\n";
else
    cout << "The index was " << (found - test) << '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks thats also really helpful, becasue thats how i need use it in my assignment :)

Answer (score 0):

Because **find** fuction a member function **string** class,You should declare a string class's object. I think you will do that like this:

```html
string test = "This is test string";
string::size_type position;
position = test.find(ID);
if (position != test.npos){
    cout << "Found: " << position << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "not found ID << endl;
}
```